# Flutter how to display datepicker when textformfield is clicked

Tags: flutter

```
new TextFormField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'DOB'),
    maxLength: 10,
    validator: validateDob,
    onSaved: (String val) {
        strDob = val;
    },
),

Future _selectDate() async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2019)
    );
    if(picked != null) setState(() => _value = picked.toString());
}
```

I created one textFormField when i click the field i want to display datepicker then i have to select one date from the picker after selecting the date i want to set the selected date in the textFormField.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Update 2020:**

As pointed by another answer @Lekr0 this can now be done using `onTap()` property of `TextFormField`.

```
TextFormField(
      onTap: (){
        // Below line stops keyboard from appearing
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

        // Show Date Picker Here

      },
    )
```

**Original Answer:**

Simple Way of Doing it :

Wrap your `TextFormField` with `IgnorePointer` & wrap `IgnorePointer` with `InkWell`

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _selectDate();   // Call Function that has showDatePicker()
        },
        child: IgnorePointer(
          child: new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'DOB'),
            maxLength: 10,
            // validator: validateDob,
            onSaved: (String val) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Also in Your `_selectDate()` make `lastDate: new DateTime(2020));`  else you will get error.

Comment: We need to change `lastDate` every year?

Comment: @JohnJoe no - we can code like - `lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365));`

Comment: I have done it but it is not showing the selected date on the TextFormField. Am I missing something?

Comment: @spycbanda I am struggling with this too. The datepicker appears but the date is not shown in the field. Did you fix it?

Comment: @ALizard Watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165902/datepicker-not-setting-input-in-textformfield

Comment: A better solution is to use TextEditingController as shown below in other answers.

Answer (score 38):

```
TextEditingController dateCtl = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
       controller: dateCtl,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: "Date of birth",
       hintText: "Ex. Insert your dob",), 
       onTap: () async{
DateTime date = DateTime(1900);
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

date = await showDatePicker(
              context: context, 
              initialDate:DateTime.now(),
              firstDate:DateTime(1900),
              lastDate: DateTime(2100));

dateCtl.text = date.toIso8601String();},)
```

Comment: you should first of all create a TextEditingController (yourController), then use it in your TextFormField, call your showDatePicker() method, fetch the value selected and insert it in your TextFormField through the command   yourController.text

Answer (score 15):

You can use *OnTap* property to achieve this

```
TextFormField(
      onTap: (){
        // Below line stops keyboard from appearing
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

        // Show Date Picker Here

      },
    )
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, there's no need of wrapping `TextFormField` within other widgets.

Comment: I'm curious, how will the resources used by the `FocusNode` be cleaned up?

Answer (score 13):

To stop keyboard from appearing, you can set the readOnly property of the TextFormField to true.

```
TextFormField(
  readOnly: true,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
TextEditingController intialdateval = TextEditingController();


Future _selectDate() async {
   DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
       context: context,
       initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
       firstDate: new DateTime(2020),
       lastDate: new DateTime(2030));
   if (picked != null)
     setState(
       () => { data.registrationdate = picked.toString(),
       intialdateval.text = picked.toString()
       }
     );
 }
TextFormField(
             // focusNode: _focusNode,
             keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
             autocorrect: false,
             controller: intialdateval,
             onSaved: (value) {
               data.registrationdate = value;
             },
             onTap: () {
               _selectDate();
               FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
             },

             maxLines: 1,
             //initialValue: 'Aseem Wangoo',
             validator: (value) {
               if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                 return 'Choose Date';
               }
             },
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               labelText: 'Registration Date.',
               //filled: true,
               icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
               labelStyle:
                   TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid),
             ),
           ),
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide some additional explanation. What are the key properties here? What was the original code missing that you've addressed here? Remember that Stack Overflow is intended to help educate future readers with similar issues, not just provide coding solutions to immediate problems.

Comment: Also, since this is coming up on two years, has six other answers, including [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128080/3025856) plus [another answer with ten votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093412/3025856), it'd be useful to offer an explanation of how your approach differs from the established answers. When might your approach might be preferred? What does it do that the original answers do not?

Answer (score 4):

```
final _dateController = useTextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: _dateController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Date',
  ),
  onTap: () async {
    await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2015),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
    ).then((selectedDate) {
      if (selectedDate != null) {
        _dateController.text =
            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(selectedDate);
      }
    });
  },
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter date.';
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you want to display DatePicker on click of `TextFormField`?

BTW you have to set `enabled=false` property of `TextFormField` and warp `TextFormField` to `GestureDetector` that has **onTap** property where you can call your DatePicker Method.

Comment: this textFormField is to enter the date of birth of the user.so i want to display datepicker when user selects the field

Answer (score -1):

> Try this!
>
> ```
> GestureDetector(
>                         onTap: () {
>                           var tm = showCupertinoDatePicker(
>                               firstDate:
>                                   defaultDateTime.add(Duration(days: -1)),
>                               lastDate: defaultDateTime.add(Duration(days: 1)),
>                               context: context,
>                               initialDate: newDate);
>                           tm.then((selectedDate) {
>                             if (selectedDate != null) {
>                               setState(() {
>                                 newDate = selectedDate;
>                               });
>                               dateController.text =
>                                   "${DateTimeUtils.formatDate(newDate)}";
>                             }
>                           });
>                         },
>                         child: AbsorbPointer(
>                           child: TextFormField(
>                               controller: dateController,
>                               autofocus: false,
>                               validator: ((val) {
>                                 if (val.trim().isEmpty) {
>                                   return “Select Date";
>                                 }
>                                 return null;
>                               }),
>                               decoration: InputDecoration(
>                                   icon: Icon(Icons.today),
>                                   suffix: Text("Tap to change",
>                                       style: Theme.of(context)
>                                           .textTheme
>                                           .caption))),
>                         ),
>                       ),
> ```
>
> I'm using all place comman widget